# Search SQL database using multiple keywords entered in a TextBox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a form with one `TextBox` for search terms to be entered by the user and it displays the results in a `ListBox`.

I know it's possible to take all the search terms and perform a `SQL` search using the words regardless of the order that they are entered.

I'm just not sure of the correct syntax for splitting the words and passing them to the SELECT command as individual search terms.

What I have currently is the following :

```
If txtDescription.Text <> "" Then
     SQL.AddParam("@Description", "%" & txtDescription.Text & "%")
     SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Description FROM PartsList WHERE Description LIKE @Description ORDER BY ID ASC;")

     For Each x As DataRow In SQL.DBDT.Rows
         lbPartsList.Items.Add(x("Description"))
     Next
End If
```

The FOR statement processes each row and adds them to a `ListBox` for display to the user.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

I have searched for solutions and most of them pertain to other languages, which I have even less knowledge about.

Comment: I think you are going to need a more complex query to test each of the terms.

Comment: You have to split and loop through your search terms and either string them together in the where clause like `where desc like 'test1' or desc like 'test2'` etc... or use the loop to concatenate multiple select statements for each search term and use "union" like `select * from pl where desc like 'test1' union select * from pl where desc like 'test2'`. The first option mentioned is more efficient for the database, but will require a little work to get the where clause built correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by creating a function on the SQL server to split character delimited string lists into a table:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[StringListToNVarcharTable]
 (@List nvarchar(MAX), @Splitter char(1))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE ([value] nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN

    IF @Splitter IS NULL
        SET @Splitter = ','

    DECLARE @pos        int,
            @nextpos    int,
            @valuelen   int

    SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

    WHILE @nextpos > 0
       BEGIN
          SELECT @nextpos = charindex(@Splitter, @list, @pos + 1)
          SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                                  THEN @nextpos
                                  ELSE len(@list) + 1
                             END - @pos - 1
          INSERT @tbl ([value])
             VALUES (convert(nvarchar(MAX), substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
          SELECT @pos = @nextpos
       END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Moving further on, once you have this function it becomes a breeze to create a stored procedure that can perform a search for you, using this function - I personally prefer pipe-separated strings but you can choose what you like.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPartDescription
@PipeDelimitedSearchString VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TblSearchStrings TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)

    IF (@PipeDelimitedSearchString IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@PipeDelimitedSearchString) > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TblSearchStrings ([value])
        SELECT [value]
        FROM StringListToNVarcharTable(@PipeDelimitedSearchString, '|')
    END

    SELECT 
        pl.PartId, 
        pl.PartName, 
        pl.PartDescription
    FROM PartsList pl
    INNER JOIN @TblSearchStrings ts ON pl.[Description] LIKE ('%' + ts.[value] + '%')
    GROUP BY
        pl.PartId, 
        pl.PartName, 
        pl.PartDescription
    ORDER BY
        pl.PartId, 
        pl.PartName, 
        pl.PartDescription
END
```

What remains now is to call the stored procedure from code.
Please note that I didn't test this code but you get the gist of it. You have a reusable function and a reusable sp and you've gotten rid of hard coded SQL queries in your code.